# Is there a way to turn on subtitles in the PC version of Assassin's Creed?

Tags: assassins-creed

I just bought the first Assassin's Creed on Steam.  The game plays fine, but the voices are difficult to make out.

Is there a way to turn on subtitles in the PC version of Assassin's Creed?

Comment: I don't have the first one installed but I _know_ that there is a subtitle setting somewhere.  Look harder.

Comment: I think there was such an option under Gameplay. But in Audio options you should be able to set all other sounds but voices simply more silent as well.

Comment: [This](http://au.gamespot.com/assassins-creed-directors-cut-edition/forum/subtitles-41766198) suggests there weren't subtitles?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to http://forums.ubi.com/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/5251069024/m/4691016806/p/3

The game on all platforms does not have subtitles.

Comment: Hm, I could have sworn there were subtitles in the game.  I always turn them on in every game I play and was pretty sure the first game was one of them.  Especially with the interleaving of English and native language in the dialogue, how else would I have understood what they were saying (and IIRC, I understood everything)?

Comment: @JeffMercado, if you *do* remember, please let me know.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a way. Go to the pause menu, then go to general, and subtitles is on the bottom of the list.

Answer (score -3):

You go to Options and General - I have used them in Revelations and ACIII

Comment: This question has already been answered, and your answer isn't entirely correct.